# How do I disable all the validators on a usercontrol?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, validation, user-controls

I need to disable validation on the user control level.  I am aware we can do this with properties. Is there a way to disable all at a once in code?  Perhaps by going through a loop or a key? (I do not need to disable all validation at the page level, only the user control level)

Comment: Why you want to do this ? You want to disable in Javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using [Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) would give you the flexibility you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a loop to disable all validator controls.

```
foreach(BaseValidator bv in this.Controls)
{
     bv.Enabled = false;
}
```

But, prefered way is use **Validation Group** if it satisfies your requirement.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this code. 1) this.Controls might contain other types of controls than validators, in which case the property assignment will fail with a NullReferenceException. 2) It's not recursive, so it might miss validators inside the control.